Multiple Neverending Stories?
We have an accepted answer for the first film, an accepted answer for the second film, and an accepted answer for the TV series (which is the dupe target for another question about the series, although I'm not sure if it's closed the right way). We've had a somewhat mixed policy on how to handle entries in a series and/or across different mediums. Do we want to merge/link these somehow?

It might be useful to link them, but I don't think they should be closed as duplicates of one another.  If we were to take that approach we'd need to figure out which of the various shows is the canonical one, and then we'd need to do the same for The War of the Worlds, The Time Machine and doubtless others.
(And how does that even work?  Do we have one canonical visual representation of TWotW and one audio one, and does that make the musical version of The War of the Worlds a duplicate of the original Orson Welles' radio drama?)
In general I don't think this works, since elements in one version may not show up, or show up differently, in another version.  If I remember the flying Martian vehicles from the 1953 movie version, and the duplicate points to the 2005 version with tripod walkers, I'm not going to recognize it as the movie I'm looking for.
I believe we should have one duplicate target per work, where that includes adaptations and remakes.  Thus Total Recall (1990) and Total Recall (2012) would be separate works with their own dupe targets.
(Aside: This is a bit of a pet peeve of mine since we have cases where, for example, the second story in a series is closed as a dupe of the first.)

if memory serves, the last time that somebody made a comment about dupe targets pointing at a question that identifies a different book in a series I said that it would be a good idea to edit the name of the book and the series into the accepted answer on the target dupe question.
